# Extracting information from oddly shaped tables with python-docx

Tags: python, python-docx

I am using `python-docx` to try and extract some information from tables in word documents. Most of my sample files work well but I have a few tables that are failing. The basic code I am running is this:

```
from docx.api import Document
document = Document(file_path)    
[[cell.text for cell in row.cells] for row in document.tables[0].rows]
```

This normally works but for some examples not all cells are read and some data is misaligned. See example below and attached file.

The failing table looks like this in word
[image]
[File](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Qvcqy01QI8UyT7lsRjjL3LSegpwtznrW/edit?usp=share_link&ouid=104601276623209492420&rtpof=true&sd=true)

and the output I get in python running my code is

```
[['', '', '', '', '', 'Nr.', '0b', '0c'],
 ['0d', '0e', '', '1b', '1c', '1d', '1e', ''],
 ['2b', '2c', '2d', '2e', '', '3b', '3c', '3d'],
 ['3e', '', '4b', '4c', '4d', '4e', '', '5b'],
 ['5c', '5d', '5e', '', '6b', '6c', '6d', '6e'],
 ['', '7b', '7c', '7d', '7e', '', '8b', '8c'],
 ['8d', '8e', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', ''],
 ['',
  'Click here to enter a date.',
  'bar    yes    no\n\nfoobar\n',
  'bar    yes    no\n\nfoobar\n',
  'bar    yes    no\n\nfoobar\n',
  'bar    yes    no\n\nfoobar\n',
  'bar    yes    no\n\nfoobar\n'],
 [],
 [],
 [],
 []]
```

What I am expecting here is something along the lines of this

```
[['', '', '', '', ''], 
 ['Nr.', '0b', '0c', '0d', '0e']
 ['1.', '1b', '1c', '1d', '1e'],
 ['2.', '2b', '2c', '2d', '2e'],
 ['3.', '3b', '3c', '3d', '3e'],
 ['4.', '4b', '4c', '4d', '4e'],
 ['5.', '5b', '5c', '5d', '5e'],
 ['6.', '6b', '6c', '6d', '6e'],
 ['7.', '7b', '7c', '7d', '7e'], 
 ['8.', '8b', '8c', '8d', '8e'],
 ['foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', ''],
 ['bar    yes    no\n\nfoobar\n',
  'bar    yes    no\n\nfoobar\n',
  'bar    yes    no\n\nfoobar\n',
  'bar    yes    no\n\nfoobar\n',
  'bar    yes    no\n\nfoobar\n']]
```

Do you have any suggestions as to why this is and how to remidy this? Note that it is not just because some cells are spanning several columns, normally this is handled semi-gracefully.

Comment: "The failing table looks like this in word" is not exactly true. The failing table has 3 extra columns on row 11 (row with 'foo') outside the table borders, the last cell containing that text 'Click here to enter a date'. That is what is messing up the row layout.